# How do I deploy my shiny app? (error opening connection)

Tags: shiny

I can't seem to deploy a shiny app. This is the error I get

```
> deployApp()
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 565580...Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '/var/folders/6_/gqrmklfs2vb00n2ksy7pthgh0000gn/T//RtmpnhMpxa/file63a82fe45b55': No such file or directory
```

I am not sure why "R" is looking in that particular location. When I go to my Shiny dashboard, I can see that the app is uploaded, but has not yet been deployed. Thanks.

Here is a minimal version of the code. It involves reading in a text file, and showing it as an .html object.

```
shinyApp(

  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("text_file", "Choose text file",
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  accept = c(".txt")
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(htmlOutput("example"))
    )
  ), 

  server <- function(input, output, session){

    text <- reactive({
      req(input$text_file)
      x <- scan(input$text_file$datapath, what = "string", sep = "\n")

    })

    # text output
    output$example <- renderUI({
      HTML(text())
    })
  }



    )
```

Comment: Please add your code or at least a min reprex for us to test.

Comment: The code extends over a few hundred lines. It's an extremely complex app. I'm not sure how it can be broken down easily into smaller chunks.

Comment: P.S. All code is in base R.

Comment: Okay - the error appears when even with a minimal example. I have posted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to add a picture hence using the answer method:

Have you tried using the RStudio functionality?

**Update**

I had to edit your code to get that option:

```
library(shiny)  

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("text_file", "Choose text file",
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  accept = c(".txt")
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(htmlOutput("example"))
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){

  text <- reactive({
    req(input$text_file)
    x <- scan(input$text_file$datapath, what = "string", sep = "\n")

  })

  # text output
  output$example <- renderUI({
    HTML(text())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: shinyapps publishing]

Comment: Cheers. The fact your code works made me realise this was not an error with the code. It was merely a case of specifying the full path to the container folder when deploying the app.

Comment: Glad I could help - albeit in a round about way.